# phpspec issue with testing if a prophecy object exists within a SplObjectStorage

Tags: php, testing, phpspec

Can anyone explain to me why the follow test isn't passing?

Code under test

```
public function doesItExist( $obj, $dataSet ){
    if( $dataSet->contains( $obj ) ){
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

phpspec test

```
function it_should_check_if_it_exists( \stdClass $s ){
    $dataSet = new \SplObjectStorage();
    $dataSet->attach($s);
    $this->doesItExist( $s, $dataSet )->shouldReturn(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the class of $s in it_should_check_if_it_exists() in the test, it's **PhpSpec\Wrapper\Collaborator**, but $obj in doesItExist() in the subject is **Double\stdClass\P1**. Obviously PHPSpec is making a double of \StdClass when it's passed to the matcher, so it's not the same object as the one that you have added to the \SplObjectStorage.